# Using vector type in R data frame

Tags: r, matrix, types, dataframe

The R language doesn't allow vectors to be variables. Why it is missing the feature? it would be nice my data frame with following features  have something like this:

```
    X1         X2     
1.  [1,2,3]   [2,3,4] <br>
2.  ....         ....
```

I tried `df <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))` but keep getting 3 rows created with numeric type instead I want a single row with vector type

Comment: You may need a list within a data.frame. If that is the case `data.frame(V1=I(list(c(1,2,3))),V2=I(list(c(1,2,3))))`

Comment: You may also use a `matrix`. Then you don't need `I` to protect the list components from coercion: `matrix(list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), ncol = 2)`.

Comment: Thanks,but I want data.frame(V1=I(as.vector(c(1,2,3))),V2=I(as.vector(c(1,2,3)))). Trying to use this data frame with neuralnet package

Comment: I doubt that any package expects such an unusual data structure. If it does, it should include a constructor for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
array(rbind(1:3, 2:4), dim = c(1, 2, 3))
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    3
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    4
```

Answer (score 0):

R does not allow to work with row data types u can have column data types. Each column can be a separate data type vector. You are not thinking the 'R' way. This short coming as you are putting it, is the strength of R. You can use an Array as suggested in the previous answer, if you strictly want to follow your chain of thought. Or just try to see how you can do what you want to do in 'R'. Rather than try to impose your known language to R.